# Confusion about the functoriality of $H_A:\mathscr A^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory, functors

For a locally small category $\mathscr A$, the functor $H_A:\mathscr A^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$ is defined as follows:

- for objects $A\in\mathscr A$: $H_A(B)=\mathscr A(B,A)$
- for arrows $g:B'\to B$ in $\mathscr A$: $H_A(g):\mathscr A(B,A)\to\mathscr A(B',A),p\mapsto p\circ g$

I'm still confused with the $^{op}$ thing. To say that $H_A$ is a functor is to say that $H_A(g\circ f)=H_A(g)\circ H_A(f)$ where $g:B'\to B, f:B''\to B'$. But the composition $H_A(g)\circ H_A(f)$ doesn't make sense. What's wrong with my application of the definition of a functor?

Comment: If, as you wrote in a comment on one of the answers, you want to stick to a notation where morphisms $g$ of $\mathcal A$ are also morphisms of $\mathcal A^{\text{op}}$, then you need to be careful with the composition operations. Writing $\circ$ for composition of morphisms in $\mathcal A$ and writing $*$ for composition of morphisms in $\mathcal A^{\text{op}}$, we have $f\circ g=g*f$. Keeping track of that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my confusion is caused by the fact that Leinster (from whose book I borrowed the definition) uses the same letter for an arrow and the arrow it corresponds to in the opposite category. First, he considers an arrow $g:B'\to B$ in $\mathscr A$. Then, on the left-hand side of $$H_A(g):\mathscr A(B,A)\to\mathscr A (B',A)\\ p\mapsto p\circ g$$

(i.e., in $H_A(g)$), $g$ no longer refers to the arrow $B'\to B$ in $\mathscr A$ but instead it refers to the corresponding arrow $B\to B'$ in $\mathscr A^{op}$ (otherwise the notation $H_A(g)$ wouldn't make sense). And then when he writes $p\mapsto p\circ g$, his $g$ again refers to the arrow $B'\to B$.

To make things more precise, one could re-define $H_A$ on arrows in this way. If $g:B'\to B$ is an arrow in $\mathscr A$, then $$H_A(g^{op}):\mathscr A(B,A)\to\mathscr A (B',A)\\ p\mapsto p\circ g$$

So suppose we have arrows $f:B''\to B'$ and $g:B'\to B$ in $\mathscr A$. Functoriality means that $$H_A(f^{op}\circ_{op}g^{op})=H_A(f^{op})\circ H_A(g^{op}).$$ By definition, we have:

- $H_A(g^{op}): \mathscr A(B,A)\to\mathscr (B',A), p\mapsto p\circ g$
- $H_A(f^{op}): \mathscr A(B',A)\to\mathscr (B'',A), q\mapsto q\circ f$
- $H_A(f^{op}\circ_{op}g^{op}): \mathscr A(B,A)\to\mathscr (B'',A), p\mapsto p\circ (f^{op}\circ_{op}g^{op})^{op}=p\circ(g\circ f)$
- $H_A(f^{op})\circ H_A(g^{op}): \mathscr A(B,A)\to\mathscr A(B',A)\to\mathscr (B'',A), p\mapsto p\circ g\mapsto (p\circ g)\circ f$

Thus $H_A(f^{op}\circ_{op}g^{op})=H_A(f^{op})\circ H_A(g^{op})$.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion is that you defined $H_A$ on $\mathscr A$, whereas it is defined on the opposite category.

So if $g: B\to B'$ is an arrow in $\mathscr A^{op}$ (it corresponds to $g:B'\to B$ in $\mathscr A$), you get a map $H_A(B)\to H_A(B')$

Similarly for composition, if $g:B\to B'$, $f:B'\to B''$ in $\mathscr A^{op}$, (they correspond to your $g:B'\to B, f: B''\to B'$ in $\mathscr A$), everything makes sense

It could help to look up the definition of contravariant functor (which isn't necessary as it is subsumed by the definition of functor, by just taking opposite categories, but if you're not at ease with them yet, it can be interesting)

Comment: I copied the definition from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf (Definition 4.1.16). As for the second paragraph of your answer, I don't see how your definition is different from mine (I didn't say explicitly that $g:B\to B'$ is an arrow in $\mathscr A^{op}$, but this is implicitly implied). A contravariant functor was defined (in the same source) as a functor from the opposite category.

Comment: Well then if your arrows are already assumed to be in the opposite category, $H_A(g) : H_A(B')\to H_A(B)$ and $H_A(f) : H_A(B'')\to H_A(B')$ so $H_A(g)\circ H_A(f)$ makes sense, and I don't see your issue. The problem with your definition is that in your definition of $H_A(g)$, some things look like they revert the direction because you took $g$ as an arrow of $\mathscr A$, not $\mathscr A^{op}$